# Django model foreignkey or charfield?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

[Django Model and Form that I want to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJgnQ.png)

Hello. I'm fairly new to Django and I have a hard time understanding which model field to use. I didn't post any code because my code is so messy right now and most of it still following "Django for Beginner" book by William S. Vincent.

I have an app consisting 2 models, `Product` model and `Production` model. Some fields on production model are linked to product model. Then from production model, I make a form for user input using `ModelForm`. (There's a link to an image to help understanding model and form relation.)

I have several questions regarding this matter.

1. If I set `product_id` on `Production` Model as `ForeignKey` to `Product`, what field should I use for `product_name` and `material`?
2. When I use `CharField` for both `product_name` and `material`, there are entry for both `product_name` and `material` on form and I don't want that. How to change it to readonly and have value updated based on `product_id`? (I'm not sure if this is related to Django form or not.)
3. Right now I'm using `ModelForm` to make `Production` form and then using `FormView` to render the form. Is it the right approach? What is the difference between this one and `CreateView` from model?

Thank you in advance for any comments and answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a name and a material on the product model, you don't need those on the production model unless they relate to the production object. If I were you, I'd have a foreign key on `Production` to the product. It might look something like;

```
class Production(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        to=Product,
        verbose_name=_("Product"),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    machine = models.CharField(
        verbose_name=_("Machine No"),
        max_length=255
    )
    date = models.DateTimeField(
        verbose_name=_("Date"),
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
```

Then your form might be;

```
class ProductionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Production

        fields = (
            'product',
            'machine',
            'date',
        )
```

I would recommend using the django admin to get your models as you want them before you start working with views. If you know the data is being stored in a way you need, then you can worry about building the frontend. The admin is around page 70 of that book you've got. You can also do readonly fields with that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems like I forgot to mention my objective. My goal is to export dataset from Production Form input as spreadsheet (.xlsx) with columns containing product_id, product_name, and material along with other fields from Production Model. From your answer, I guess the best approach is to make a new model only containing those three field, then use ForeignKey  on Product Model and Production Model to that new model (I'm not sure about this, please correct me if I'm wrong) ?

Comment: Import and export is really easy, right in the admin. So just focus on setting up your admin, then look into this package to get data in and out; https://pypi.org/project/django-import-export/